# Rails 7 : Multiple forms/buttons on one page, each one supposed to trigger same action but with different input, always triggers the first in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, stimulusjs, form-with

Here's the issue I'm facing.
I'm creating miniature cards for my models, iterate on every item of the collection (using render @models) and each one has a button to trigger a form (POST) that goes to my controller action, and adds its id to my session cookies.
However, now I notice that, whereas I didn't change any value on this side, it keeps triggering the same form in the iteration, the 1st **(my controller always adds the value "1" to my form).**

I'm using Rails 7, Ruby 3.1.1 and it started doing this for no reason. I was implementing Stimulus Controllers (to add AJAX responsiveness) when it just started bugging.

Here's a part of my form :

```
    <%= form_with(url: devis_path, method: :post, remote: true, data: {manage_cart_target: "form", action: "submit->manage-cart#manage"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :tool_id, value: tool.id %>
      <%= tool.id %> # this part works and does display the expected value
      <%= f.submit "Ajouter à mon devis", class: "mt-4 text-xl w-full text-white py-2 rounded-xl shadow-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-400", style: "background-color: #3949ab" %>
    <% end %>
```

And here's the part of my controller that's involved :

```
 def manage
    puts params # that's how I confirmed that it always sent "1" and none of the other ids on the page
    unless session[:cart]
      session[:cart] = []
    end
    # * If requests arrives with an index in params, it means it's to be deleted
    if params[:index]
      index_to_delete = params[:index].to_i
      session[:cart].delete_at(index_to_delete)
    end

    # * otherwise, if request arrives with a tool_id it's pushing it in the cart array
    if params[:tool_id]
      session[:cart] << params[:tool_id].to_i
      flash[:notice] = "Hey !"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json
      end
    end

  end
```

It is a design choice not to create any record or to use any model for this and to store the value in cookies rather than DB.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is, that all the fields in your forms have the exact same ID, even if the actual url of your `form_with` is different and even if there are multiple forms. the requests intefer. You can work around that problem by assigning the inputs or in your case the hidden_field a unique id.

`<%= f.hidden_field :tool_id, value: tool.id, id: "tool_id_#{tool.id}" %>`

If you are planning on adding a label at some point you need to assign that id as `for:` for that label too.

`<%= f.label :tool_id, for: "tool_id_#{tool.id}" %>`

Hope that helps.

Comment: It was this indeed, thanks a lot ! 
The call was triggering the first Stimulus controller, not the one I was actually targeting.